# Composite Key,Your primary key is not unique

Tags: android, composite-key, sqlite

I have a table that using composite key as primary key. this is my create table code.

```
private static final String db_createorderdtl = "create table  if not exists "
      + ORDER_DTL + "("
      + ORDER_ID +" varchar not null, "
      + COLUMN_ID+ " integer not null, "
      + QUANTITY + " varchar(3) not null," +
      " foreign key ("+ORDER_ID+") references "+TABLE_ORDER+"("+ORDER_ID+"),"+
      " foreign key ("+COLUMN_ID+") references "+TABLE_NAME+"("+COLUMN_ID+"), "+
      "primary key  ("+ORDER_ID+"," +COLUMN_ID+ "));";
```

when i insert into this table more than one item, (same ORDER_ID, different COLUMN_ID), there is no problem with the first item, but when the second item inserted, i have an error which tells that my primary key is not unique refer to ORDER_ID. like the program is not understand that i am using a composite key. Should i declare something in my program's code? this is my inserted code:

```
    public orderdtl createorderdtl(String orderid, String Id, String qty) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBHelper.ORDER_ID, orderid);
    values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_ID, Id);
    values.put(DBHelper.QUANTITY, qty);

    database.insert(DBHelper.ORDER_DTL, null,values);

    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.ORDER_DTL,
        allorderdtl, DBHelper.ORDER_ID + "=" + orderid, null,
        null, null, null);
    orderdtl neworderdtl = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        neworderdtl = cursorToorderdtl(cursor);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return neworderdtl;
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you're not setting a `COLUMN_ID` in your ContentValues object that is used for the insert operation. However, `COLUMN_ID` is part of the primary key and maybe it defaults to 0 on each insert. That's probably the cause for the primary key not unique error.

Comment: What are the actual values of `orderid` and `Id` in both cases?

Comment: orderid =yyyyMMddhhmmss example 20140125123030 and id =1,2,3 autoincrement

Comment: @CL. orderid =yyyyMMddhhmmss example 20140125123030 and id =1,2,3 autoincrement

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @CL.error insert into orderdtl (orderid,id,qty) values ('20140123120530','1','5'), primary key is not unique (orderid=20140123120530)